# ImageJ: How to remove image artifacts due to dirty camera lenses?

Tags: noise-cancellation

I have an image of interest
[image: Hydrogel] and would like to remove the artifacts from it (black dots, which are probably dust on camera lenses). [image: Artifacts] How can I do it using the ImageJ (FIJI)?

Comment: You should probably ask the program's developers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about specific use of a software tool and not about SP.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two ways to do it:

1. I can use image calculator and divide image of interest by background image and display the result in a new window as 32-bit (float) result. But the photo will be black and white.
2. Or adjust color threshold for background image in such a way that only the noise will be filtered and than select it. On the image of interest restore selection and apply filter, for example, Gaussian Blur. Sometimes you might want to subtract background from image with noise (like in my case, the right side was much darker that the left).
   [image]

Subtracted background + applied color threshold
[image]

Final result: image of interested after the Gaussian Blur filter was applied to a restored selection made from previous photo.
[image]

There is also another way to do it [explained here [Removing Image Artifacts Due to Dirty Camera Lenses and Thin Occluders](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ravir/dirtylens.pdf)] as well as applying wavelet and Fourier transform, but unfortunately I have not got so far. Would appreciate if somebody can explain the datails.

Answer (score 0):

This type of disturbance is [salt and pepper noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt-and-pepper_noise) and is usually dealt with using a [median filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter).

However, the spots in this image are relatively large (~30x30 px) and the median might severely distort the surrounding areas. Here is an example:

[image]

Now, if you cannot get to the dust what you could do is use multiple takes and stack the images up. But you will need to use some form of template to ensure that successive takes align perfectly with each other.

You can achieve this by drawing 3 dots on the transparency with a fine tip pen and then align the images on those three dots.

An easy strategy would be to devise a template by which you shoot one picture of the transparency, flip it once horizontally (now the dust obstructs a different part of the image) and then once more vertically (now the dust again obstructs a different part of the image).

When you scan these three images, they only differ in orientation which is very easily recovered (just flip the image). Flip them all back so that they are all in the same orientation and then align the three marker dots to make sure that all pictures are aligned pixel-to-pixel.

Then, simply stack the images and "copy" the pixels across different locations (manually) or stack them using a median filter (that is, in the vertical direction, across images).

This technique works better with scanned images and will also work with document scanners with overhead cameras as long as the document is not too big (otherwise you will have geometric distortions).

Here is what I mean using your "noise only" picture from above:

**Take 1:**

[image]

**Take 2:**

[image]

**Take 3:**

[image]

You can keep flipping the image if you like, until it comes back upright (to what it would look like in *Take 1*).

As you can see, with this process, the noise disrupts different parts of the image each time and when you can't "access" a particular set of pixels because of the speck in one image you can copy it from another.

Hope this helps.

P.S. The above can be implemented in any image processing software. I used [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) here but I am sure that ImageJ would have an elementary median filter too.

Comment: @Olena You are welcome. If you found this response helpful you can upvote and / or accept it via the arrow and checkpoint controls on the left of the answer. Good luck with your project.